# Why am I disconnected for being AFK in single player?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've seen people AFK for an hour in multiplayer, yet God forbid I be AFK for more than 5 minutes when I'm by myself. Because you know, there's no harm in messing up the game for other players, but if you're by yourself then you're a criminal.

Why does this happen? I want to hear a good explanation for this.

Comment: One of the curses of serve-client based gaming unfortunately. I feel your pain, but this measure is necessary!

Comment: The last time I played Diablo, I was able to AFK for hours in single-player. Maybe it's because my games were open for friends to join, so Blizzard counted it as multiplayer. Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: I usually have on problem afking for long periods of time, though every once in a while it kicks me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a measure to reduce server load by terminating inactive clients. When you go afk in a multiplayer game, it doesn't cost the server much resources to keep you around since there are other players who are using that instance anyway (though personally I'd love to see auto kicking of afk'ers in public games).

Answer (score 3):

You get disconnected in Single Player games as you can easily exploit the game and there is unnecessary load on the servers.

There was this exploit where you open an Act 2 game and go near one of those (green, blue, red) obelisks that spawn spiders on a regular basis. With enough armor, health regeneration and damage on hit you could kill them by just standing there. They drop some gold, so you could easily do this all day and collect the money from time to time. I bet there are many similar spots throughout the game.

In Multiplayer games it is different. The monsters get more difficult, so no one will accept someone just standing there doing nothing, as they have to do more to get the same amount of loot. At least I would leave and create my own Singleplayer game.

Comment: pretty sure at least some of those exploits (like the obelisk one you mentioned) have been fixed

Comment: I still don't see why this wouldn't apply multiplayer just as well as single-player